# Are questions about Google Assistant actions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I had a question where I'm facing problems with IFTTT integration of Google Assistant and Trello.

Though it feels very much on-topic, I can't find any `google-assistant` tags and Google Assistant isn't a web application.

Are such questions on topic?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. As you observe, the Google Assistant isn't a web application. However, IFTTT is. Perhaps if you gave us a preview of the question you'd like to ask, we can offer more concrete suggestions.

Comment: It's more of a Google Assistant issue than an IFTTT one. I think I'll ask this one on android enthusiasts SE and see how it goes

Answer (score 3):

I would be more inclined to ask this on the [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) site.

There are plenty of Google Assistant questions [there](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-assistant).
Including [at least one](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/2556/3615) about integration with IFTTT.